# Change array inside multiple functions via pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have following code, and I want to change array passed trough  multiple functions like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *arr, n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //scanning into array

    func1(arr, n);
}
```

> **Now I want each loop to change array and then use the changed arr in next loop etc**

```
void func1(int *x, int h)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < height; i++)
        change(&x, h, i);
}
```

> **Here I need to change the original array to be same as gArr or have same values**

```
void change(int **x, int h, int i) {


    int *gArr = (int*)malloc(h*sizeof(int));
    //doing some operations


    //here I want to somehow change the original array to be gArr 
    //or to have the same values as gArr
    *x = gArr;
}
```

I've tried multiple approaches and I somehow can't get the right result, thanks for help.

Comment: No, I need to change it in `change` because I need to use it again in main, and I need it to be the same array.

Comment: I think in `change()` second last line should be `*x = gArr;`

Comment: You need to remember location of heap where malloc allocates memory.

Comment: Yes it was meant to be `*x = gArr` , can you provide some example in this particular case?

Comment: you should probably use `memcpy(*x, gArr, n);` instead of `*x = gArr;` and don't forget to `free` all the allocated memory when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Your call graph is:

```
main(void)
    func1(int *x)
        change(int **x)
```

so if you pass a pointer variable from `main`, through `func1` to `change` and then change the variable (i.e. the memory location pointed to), then you must also pass its address to `func1`, otherwise `main` can never observe the change:

```
main(void)
    func1(int **x)
        change(int **x)
```

...and don't forget to `free` the original array in `change`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between a pointer to an array, and the elements of that array. Let's first go through what you're doing right now:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *arr, n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    // ...
    func1(arr, n);
}
```

`int *arr` declares a **pointer** to an `int` in the scope of the function `main()`.
At some pointer later you pass this pointer to the function `func1`. Now C is a pass by value language, that means that `func1` gets the value of `arr`, and that value is the address of your dynamically allocated array. This allows your to manipulate the elements that `arr` points to, but not `arr` itself. So if inside `func1` you have:

```
void func1(int *arr, int n) {
   arr = dynamic_pointer_to_another_array();
}
```

only the `arr` inside of `func1` is gonna change but not the one in `main`. Now you've partially figured that out, because your `change()` function takes a pointer to pointer instead, however in `func1()` you have:

```
change(&arr, h, i);
```

You might think the `&` here is passing the address of `arr` from `main`, but it's actually passing the address of `arr` from `func1`, because once again C is a **pass by value** language. Every time you pass a value to a function it gets copied to that function's scope, and any operations on the value won't be reflected in the caller.

The simple solution to this is to change `func1` to take a `int **arr` instead of `int *arr`, that way you can do:

```
change(arr, h, 1);
```

and inside `change` you can then do:

```
*arr = new_array();
```

This would work because then you're passing the address of the pointer instead of the pointer itself, and through the address of the pointer you can change what the pointer points to.

## Important Note

Your code has another huge problem. You're dynamically allocating an array and then trying to reassign the pointer to that array to another array. This is gonna certainly cause memory leaks and dangling pointers. Doing

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
arr = new_array();
```

is guaranteed to cause memory leaks, because you never use `free` on that pointer to deallocate the memory, and after you reassign it to another array, you lose all references to it. You have a couple of options of how to go about this. If you need to grow the size of `arr` then you use `realloc` instead of allocating a new array. That way you'll still have to only `free` once.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is your change of altering value inside the address doesn't take affect right, `HOW COULD IT BE UPDATED`, when you are dealing with a copy of the array you made in the main.

I've seen you have used int** type inside the parameter list of the function `change(int**, int, int)`. And the reason to use this because the change can take effect on the passed array right!

In the same way, You should also use int** inside like this func1(int**) so that operation can reflect on the original one.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow figured it out this way:

```
void func1(int *x, int h)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < height; i++)
            change(x, h, i);
    }


void change(int *x, int h, int i) {

    int *gArr = (int*)malloc(h*sizeof(int));
     //doing some operations

    memcpy(x, gArr, h*sizeof(int));
    free(gArr);
}
```

`memcpy` did the job, but I'm not sure if its the right approach.

Comment: if you generate an array of data to copy it directly over x why don't you use directly x?

Comment: Because there are some operations where I need to persist the original array, it wouldn't work that way.